# Put fragment from ViewPager to bundle

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to somehow save the fragment from ViewPager to bundle and restore it again.
But when I try to use `getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(bundle, "key", fragment)`, it throws exception that fragment is not added to the fragment manager. How can I save the fragment from the ViewPager and restore it again?

Comment: you need to serialise it before putting it into bundle !!

Comment: @dex Could you please explain it?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you're trying yo save your fragment? Try to call putFragment after you've called setAdapter to the ViewPager. Also you  can't save fragment if it's not visible.

Comment: So if you want to put object inside bundle first you need to make that data as serialisable [ in case of fragment you need to have public empty constructor in fragment ] rest system will re-store them. ]. You can google it serialisation of data in android, I am sure you will get plenty of good links